# “Arithmetic overflow” error

Tags: counters, calculations

factorials up to 12 are handled.How can make it to compute beyond that?

> Error: “Arithmetic overflow

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document} 
\newcount\n \newcount\p \newcount\m
\def\factorial#1{{\m=#1\advance\m by 1
\n=1
\p=1
\loop\ifnum\n<\m \multiply\p by \n \advance\n by 1 \repeat\number\p}}

\def\printfactorials#1{\m=#1\advance\m by 1
\n=0
\loop\ifnum\n<\m \hfil\break\number\n! = \factorial{\n} \advance\n by 1 \repeat}

\printfactorials{12}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ! Arithmetic overflow.
\iterate ->\ifnum \n <\m \multiply \p by \n 
                                            \advance \n by 1 \relax \expanda...
l.16 \printfactorials{13}

Comment: The largest integer that can be used in TeX is 2^31-1 = 2147483647 and 13! exceeds it. TeX is *not* a computer algebra system, but a typesetting engine.

Comment: Perhaps look at the `bigintcalc` package, but as @egreg says this is not really the primary purpose of TeX.

Answer (score 12):

Using [`bigintcalc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bigintcalc) (from the [`oberdiek` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/oberdiek)), you can obtain the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigintcalc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/bigintcalc
\begin{document} 
\newcount\n \newcount\p \newcount\m
\def\factorial#1{%
  {\m=#1\advance\m by 1
   \n=1
   \p=1
   \loop\ifnum\n<\m \multiply\p by \n \advance\n by 1 \repeat\number\p}}
\def\printfactorials#1{%
  \m=#1\advance\m by 1
  \n=0
  \loop\ifnum\n<\m \hfil\break\number\n! = \factorial{\n} \advance\n by 1 \repeat}

\def\bigfactorial#1{%
  \bigintcalcFac{#1}%
}
\def\printbigfactorials#1{%
  \m=#1\advance\m by 1
  \n=0
  \loop\ifnum\n<\m \hfil\break\number\n! = \bigfactorial{\the\n} \advance\n by 1 \repeat}

%\printfactorials{12}
\printbigfactorials{20}
\end{document} ​
```

`\bigintcalcXXX` is the basic operators that are defined. `\bigintcalcFac{<x>}` returns the factorial of `<x>`. According to the [`bigintcalc` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/bigintcalc.pdf),

> Package `bigintcalc` defines arithmetic operations that deal with big
> integers. Big integers can be given either as explicit integer number
> or as macro code that expands to an explicit number. *Big* means that
> there is no limit on the size of the number. Big integers may exceed
> TeX's range limitation of -2147483647 and
> 2147483647. Only memory issues will limit the usable range.

Comment: You lost a fi :-)

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Honestly, I was searching my code for a lost `\fi`. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if I wasted your time with my joke. Copy-paste from PDF can be a nuisance...

Answer (score 9):

Well mostly the same as Werners answer, but I made an "elementary" implementation of `\factorial` :-)

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{bigintcalc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\begin{document} 
\def\factorial#1{{\edef\m{\bigintcalcInc{#1}}%
\def\n{1}%
\def\p{1}%
\loop\ifnum\n<\m\relax\edef\p{\bigintcalcMul\p\n}\edef\n{\bigintcalcInc\n}\repeat\p}}

\def\printfactorials#1{\edef\m{\bigintcalcInc{#1}}%
\def\n{0}%
\loop\ifnum\n<\m\relax \hfil\break\n! = \factorial{\n}
\edef\n{\bigintcalcInc\n}\repeat}
\footnotesize
\printfactorials{70}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Well, in fact it wouldn't be neccessary to use `bigintcalc` in `\printfactorials`. `\edef\p{\bigintcalcMul\p\n}` is really the only place where it is needed.